# ASP.NET MVC4 Web API Controller Stuck on One Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I created a new ASP.NET MVC4 Web Api Project. In addition to the default `ValuesController`, I added another controller, `ScenarioController`. It has the exact same methods as `ValuesController`. But for some reason, it behaves differently.

```
/api/values/ => "value1","value2"
/api/values/1 => "value"
/api/scenario/ => "value1","value2"
/api/scenario/1 => "value1","value2"
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                   should return "value"!
```

Using breakpoints, I know that `/api/scenario/1` actually gets sent to the `public IEnumerable<string> Get()`, not the expected `public string Get(int id)`. Why?

For reference, here are the relevant files (these are pristine default mvc4-webapi classes, haven't modified anything):

**Global.asax.cs**

```
namespace RoutingTest
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
namespace RoutingTest
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
            // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
            // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
            //config.EnableQuerySupport();

            // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
            // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        }
    }
}
```

**ValuesController.cs**

```
namespace RoutingTest.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

**ScenarioController.cs** (yes, it's in the Controllers folder)

```
namespace RoutingTest.Controllers
{
    public class ScenarioController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/scenario
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/scenario/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gremlins**. Thanks to @Pete Klien for verifying that the code does work outside my machine. Here's what I did.

1. Experienced problem of Controller only using 1 method for Get in original project.
2. Created new Web Api project, with code that I posted in the question. Same symptom.
3. Clean Project, Rebuild All, still no dice.
4. Reboot machine, clean, rebuild, try again, no dice.
5. Create new Web Api project **in new solution**, *success!*

Comment: ...aaaaaand, the problem is back. I've been setting the new solution up with the code & config from the non-working project, and when testing the first (newly-added) controller, found the same issue of only using the un-parameterized Get method!

Comment: welp, it helps to keep your controller method parameter names and the routing config parameter names the same, kids.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code just now and got the expected result:

```
> curl http://localhost:53803/api/values
["value1","value2"]
> curl http://localhost:53803/api/values/1
"value"
> curl http://localhost:53803/api/scenario
["value1","value2"]
> curl http://localhost:53803/api/scenario/1
"value"
>
```

(By the way, there is no requirement that it be in the `Controllers` folder.  `HttpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute` simply finds all your classes that inherit from `ApiController`.)

I am not being sarcastic when I suggest that you *Rebuild All* and try again.

Comment: Thanks for trying to dupe it. Yeah, I did a restart and also created the new project to duplicate what I was seeing in another project, and was rather surprised when it did the same thing. Many Clean Project and Rebuild All have been done :(

Comment: I'm not experienced in asp.net mvc--is there anything else that can affect the configuration such that this could be happening? NuGet package? .NET 4.0 vs 4.5?

Comment: Just created a new *solution*, with the same code, and that does work correctly.

Comment: This feels like the server, either IIS or VS's internal one, was holding on to an old build.  I should have asked which server you were debugging on.

Comment: FWIW, I was using the VS2012 internal server. It was weird because I could alter other services and see the difference, but this one just would not change!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and could not get anything to work.  Finally I changed the port on the IIS Express Project Url setting and all is back to normal.  It was localhost:57846.  I just made it localhost:57847 and all is back to normal.